# Filter wrong Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A_Random>
    <A_RandomType>
     <RandomType>T4fV</RandomType>
        <RandomOrganization>1012</RandomOrganization>
        <RandomChannel>12</RandomChannel>
        <RandomDivision>00</RandomDivision>
        <RandomGroup>112</RandomGroup>
        <to_Item>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <RandomChrgItemText>null</RandomChrgItemText>
                <Material/>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>STK</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1088</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material>1111</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1088</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material>594172</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1010</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material/>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1010</Plant>
            </A_RandomTypeItemType>
                <RandomChrgItemText>null</RandomtChrgItemText>
                <Material/>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1044</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomeItemType>
                <Material>482803</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1788</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material>594172</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1788</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
        </to_Item>
    </A_RandomType>
</A_Random>
```

I want to accomplish the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A_Random>
    <A_RandomType>
     <RandomType>T4fV</RandomType>
        <RandomOrganization>1012</RandomOrganization>
        <RandomChannel>12</RandomChannel>
        <RandomDivision>00</RandomDivision>
        <RandomGroup>112</RandomGroup>
        <to_Item>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material>1111</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1088</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material>594172</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1010</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomeItemType>
                <Material>482803</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1788</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
            <A_RandomItemType>
                <Material>594172</Material>
                <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
                <RequestedQuantityUnit>PC</RequestedQuantityUnit>
                <Plant>1788</Plant>
            </A_RandomItemType>
        </to_Item>
    </A_RandomType>
</A_Random>
```

In short, I want to copy everything except nodes where Material is empty or A_RandomItemType is set to null. I have nothing working but one of my tries was the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name(  ) != 'Material:null']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name(  ) != 'SalesOrderWthoutChrgItemText:null']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tanks for your help. Can you pleas explein me why my code dont work?

Comment: *"A_RandomItemType is set to null."* What exactly does this mean? There is no such thing as "set to null" in XML/XSLT.

Comment: Also the input you show is not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach for this type of problem is to use the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template to copy everything *as is*, and add an empty template (or templates) for the nodes you want to remove - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove A_RandomItemType where Material is empty --> 
<xsl:template match="A_RandomItemType[not(Material/text())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. Thanks this solved my problem. Here ist the fully solution i used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove A_RandomItemType where Material is empty --> 
<xsl:template match="A_RandomItemType[not(Material/text())]"/>
<xsl:template match="A_RandomItemType[(RandomChrgItemText/text() = 'null')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:template match="A_RandomItemType[(RandomChrgItemText/text() = 'null')]"/>` The parentheses are redundant. You can do simply `<xsl:template match="A_RandomItemType[RandomChrgItemText='null']"/>`.